# Use aggregation to match for documents element

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I don't know how to formulate this question, so I would better show by example.

Suppose I have documents stored in the following format:

```
{'category': [1, 2, 3, ...],
'delete': [2, ...]}
```

How to receive document only with "categories" that does not need to be "deleted"? The result of aggregation must be:

```
{'category': [1, 3]}
```

I try to do it in the following way, first I unwind all categories

```
{'$unwind': '$category'},
```

Then I want to use $match, to match only for categories that are not in "delete", but I get an error:  **$nin needs an array**

```
{'$match': {'category': {'$nin': '$delete'}}}
```

I do not understand why "$delete" is not an array?

Answer (score 4):

In the upcoming 2.6 release of MongoDB, the new [`$setDifference`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) aggregation framework operator makes this straightforward, see example below using the current release candidate:

```
$ ./mongo --port 31100
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0-rc0
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:31100/test
test-rs0:PRIMARY> db.foo.insert({category: [1, 2, 3], delete : [2] })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
test-rs0:PRIMARY> db.foo.aggregate(
...     { $project : { diff : { $setDifference : [ "$category", "$delete" ] } } } )
{ "_id" : ObjectId("530ddc2845cec73af61c81c1"), "diff" : [ 1, 3 ] }
test-rs0:PRIMARY>
```

[MongoDB 2.6-rc0](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) was released last week so the production version should be available soon.

Answer (score 2):

So given the condition:

```
{"$match": {"category": {"$nin": "$delete" } }}
```

You receive an error that the type of argument for $nin is not an array.

Also consider the following

```
{$match: {"category": { "$nin": ["$delete"] } }}
```

And this does not match, as neither does:

```
{"$unwind": "$delete" },
{"$match": {"category": {"$ne": "$delete"}}}
```

But of course either form of this will:

```
{"$match": {"category": { "$nin": [2] } }}
```

or:

```
{"$unwind": "$delete" },
{"$match": {"category": {"$ne": 2 }}}
```

So as you can see the "$delete" reference is **not** expanding in the way you are expecting. it does not do so in these cases and only does so in the $project and $group operator stages.

You need to use the literal as shown in the last two cases.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the goal of the question poster, which is to return documents that contain only the categories that do not need to be deleted.  Using literal values in the aggregation pipeline doesn't help with this goal since the deleted category values in each document may be different.

Comment: @JonRangel While there is other logic than can be done with sets, I believe it does address the fact that the expected expansion that the question proposed does not work. It's true that this is a "set math" problem and that there will be appropriate tools. But as of writing, not for production.